# how to parse email header in php?

Tags: php, parsing, email, header

I will be passing string containing raw email in which i want to parse headers. Might be Subject, text/html or attachments etc. Please help me on this.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: zneak, if somebody send me email from that i want to fetch header like (subject, body, text/html) etc. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's other libraries too, but this was my first hit on google.
http://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser/

You will either needs to find the input in `$_SERVER['argv']` or use `fopen('php://input', 'r')`

Answer (score 0):

this can all be done with the php [imap](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) functions

Answer (score -1):

Just use php's [regex](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php) functions.